# latex: xspace not suppressing space in combination with textit

Tags: latex, xspace

I put xspace at the end of most of my macros, e.g.

```
\newcommand*{\foobar}{foobar\index{foobar}\xspace}
```

but I just discovered that if the macro is placed inside `textit`, it does not work as expected, e.g.

```
Test 1: \foobar. Test 2: \textit{\foobar}.
```

produces

> Test 1: foobar. Test 2: *foobar* .

with an extra space before the `.` character. Of course I could make a duplicate non-xspace macro for these case, but can I fix this more properly in some way?

Comment: Dear moderator that closed this question, can you please describe in what way defining a latex macro does not "relate to programming or software development in some way"?

Comment: I think it is because we have other sites specifically for latex!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer "hidden" in /usr/share/texmf/doc/latex/tools/xspace.pdf:

> Sometimes \xspace may make the wrong
>   decision, and add a space when it is
>   not required. There may be different
>   reasons for this behavior but it can
>   always be handled by following the
>   macro with {}, as this has the effect
>   of suppressing the space.

So

```
Test 3: \textit{\foobar{}}.
```

produces

> Test 3: *foobar*.